# flash session not working in Middleware Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I am newcomer in Laravel. I have a problem with session flash in Middleware.
In Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
       {
            if(auth()->check()){
                return $next($request);
            }else{
                Notification::error('Please login');
                return redirect()->route('admin.auth.login.get')->with('test',' session');
            }

        }
```

In View:

I get Nofitication but nothing happen. I check with flash session (session('test'))-> nothing happen.

Please help to explain me why it dont work? and what's solution?.

Thank you very much and sorry about my English.

Comment: Add your routes.php file

Comment: My issue is solved. Thank you anyway.

Comment: For those who still can't get it working, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279871/laravel-5-2-session-flash-not-working-even-with-web-middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your route in `web` middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
});
```

See this
[basic-routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#basic-routing)

Make sure that in `kernel.php`
 `web` Middleware is

```
        'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

    ],
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer quickly .I've added middle=>'web' already  but it's still not working. This is my code in Route.php
<Br/>
Route::group(array('middleware'=>'web'),function(){
 Route::get('auth/register', array('as'=>'admin.auth.register.get','uses'=>'AuthController@getRegister'));
 Route::post('auth/register', array('as'=>'admin.auth.register.post','uses'=>'AuthController@postRegister'));
 Route::get('auth/login', array('as'=>'admin.auth.login.get','uses'=>'AuthController@getLogin'));
 Route::post('auth/login', array('as'=>'admin.auth.login.post','uses'=>'AuthController@postLogin'));
});

Comment: It's not working. It's still nothing happen, i don't know why :(

Comment: I create middware in App\Modules\Admin\Http\Middleware because i use a module package. Do you think it is the cause of the error?

Comment: Thanks Pananoid so much, I've solved this issue, The problem is the position which I put auth middleware before web middleware so it dont work. Now when I put web middleware before auth middleware, it work perfectly. Thanks pananoid again.

Comment: Thanks @liemphan your last comment solved my problem here