# Laravel 5.2 Session flash not working even with web middleware

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, flash-message

I am trying to implement flash messaging using sessions but am unable to do so.

In my controller I have:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    session()->flash('donald', 'duck');
    session()->put('mickey', 'mouse');
    return redirect()->action('CustomerController@index')->with('bugs', 'bunny');
}
```

But when I check the session variables in the view, I can only see the values from `session()->put('mickey', 'mouse')`.

Session:

```
{"_token":"F6DoffOFb17B36eEJQruxvPe0ra1CbyJiaooDn3F","_previous":{"url":"http:\/\/localhost\/customers\/create"},"flash":{"old":[],"new":[]},"mickey":"mouse"}
```

A lot of people encountered this problem by not having the relevant routes inside the web middleware. I made sure to do this as well but it still wouldn't work.

In routes.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::get('/customers', 'CustomerController@index');
    Route::get('/customers/create', 'CustomerController@create');
    Route::post('/customers', 'CustomerController@store');
});
```

In Kernel.php:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

Can anyone let me know what I could be doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: please share the code how you check session.

Comment: To check the session, I added `<pre>{{ json_encode(session()->all()) }}</pre>` to the view

Comment: that's not a system to check session.

Comment: Why not? It lets me see what's inside the session array in the resulting view

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Fixed the issue by replacing

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
   ...
});
```

with

```
Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => ['web']], function () {
   ...
});
```

No idea why this works though when all the documentation suggests that we use `['middleware' => ['web']]`

Comment: In your case, ['middleware' => 'web'] will work too. But 'web' middleware doesn't work when we are giving array of middlewares. Though it's not in any documentation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried ['middleware' => 'web'] as well but it didn't work

Comment: Thaks for saving my time. I was having the same issue like yours. Looks like the documentation should be there to tell about this.

Comment: Had ['middleware' => 'web'] and it wasn't working, but with middlewareGroups worked as expected

Answer (score 5):

This is more than likely because of a change that was made to the Laravel framework (v5.2.27) that all routes by default are part of the "web" middleware, so assigning it again in your routes.php file ends up assigning it twice.

The solution is either to remove the "web" middleware from your routes OR remove the automatic assignment from the RouteServiceProvider.

Before the Laravel update:

```
// RouteServiceProvider.php
$router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
    require app_path('Http/routes.php');
});
```

After the Laravel update:

```
// RouteServiceProvider.php
$router->group([
    'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
], function ($router) {
    require app_path('Http/routes.php');
});
```

Notice how the new update automatically applies the "web" middleware to all routes. Simply remove it here if you wish to continue using Laravel 5.2 as you have before (manually assigning "web" middleware in your routes.php).

Comment: This is key! Thank you.. spent hours on this.

Answer (score 1):

Build your Session flash info by using this code:

```
<?php

Session::flash("Donald", "Duck")
// Or in your code style.
$request->session()->flash("Donald", "Duck")
?>
```

Check it in your view with:

```
@if(Session::has("Donald")
    {{Session::get("Donald")}}
@endif
```

You forget to use $request :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tested this earlier and using $request didn't make a difference :( As far as I know, using `session()` without the `$request` is valid -- the one without `$request` invokes the `session()` helper (laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-session). Also, it doesn't explain why "bugs":"bunny" doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

In Controller:

```
use Session,Redirect;

public function store(Request $request) 
{
Session::flash('donald', 'duck');
Session::put('mickey', 'mouse');
return Redirect::to('/customers')->with('bugs', 'bunny');
}
```

In 'view' check the data is getting or not:

```
<?php
print_r($bugs);die;
?>
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: He said he is not getting the 'bugs','bunny'. for that he should redirect to the proper route like this return Redirect::to('/customers')->with('bugs', 'bunny'); And your answer is also correct. @Chilion

Comment: Sorry tested it multiple times and it still doesn't work. Although there was something strange where the 'donald' key appeared in the session but without the 'duck' value

Comment: @howellmartinez try this : Session::keep(['donald', 'duck']); or Session::reflash();

Comment: `session()->keep(['donald'])` will result in session having `"flash":{"new":["donald"],"old":[]}` but still no "donald":"duck" key-value pair

Answer (score 1):

I use the following:

In my controller:

```
public function xyz(){
   // code

   // This
   return redirect()->action('homeController@index')->with('success', 'Check! Everything done!');

    // Or this
    return redirect('/index')->with('success', 'Check! Everything done!');
}
```

In my view:

```
@if(session('success'))
    {{ session('success') }}
@endif
```

Nothing else. The web-middleware is assigned to every route.

Comment: Yes this code should work although it is very unusual that I can't get it to. I have another Laravel 5.2 project with a similar routes and controllers setup and sessions work fine. For this project, I even tried to do a brand new install but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why but on Windows you need changes in your routes: middleware to middlewareGroups, like that:

[image: change middleware to middlewareGroups]

So, in your app\Kernel.php, you need put the StartSession at first on array of middleware group web:

[image: put the StartSession at first on array of middleware group web]