# Session flash not working, put does [L5.2]

Tags: php, laravel, flash, session, laravel-5

Pretty basic things going on. Using `Session Flash` messages to display any success/error messages.

All routes are set-up in my `'middleware' => 'web'` group.

Now my problem. `->flash()` does not work whilst `->put()` does.

Controller:

```
$request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'My flash message');
```

Blade:

```
@foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
    @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))
        <p class="alert alert-{{ $msg }}">{{ Session::get('alert-' . $msg) }} <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        </p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

The `return redirect('routeHere')->with('alert-success', 'My flash message');`
 stated in the [Laravel 5 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) doesn't work either.

**Edit**

[Laravel 5.2 Session flash not working even with web middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279871/laravel-5-2-session-flash-not-working-even-with-web-middleware?rq=1) duplication. Using `['middlewareGroups' => 'web']` instead of `['middleware' => 'web']` does fix the problem but assuming this is not the way to go.

Comment: Are You sure that You want to use it in the closest next request. Because `flash` works only for the next request... and if you want to get this messsage in any request later You should use `put`.

Comment: Yes, I want that. Same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279871/laravel-5-2-session-flash-not-working-even-with-web-middleware?rq=1 (Using `middlewareGroups` instead of `middleware` does work but is not the way to go I assume.

Comment: Could You dump in a view: `{{dd($request->session()->all())}}`

Comment: `DDing` a $request in view obviously doesn't work, but I get what you mean. It won't return the flashed session data

Answer (score 0):

After searching around out of curiosity for this problem i noticed an interesting update for laravel `version >= 5.2.27` that applies by default  the web middleware group to all the routes defined in routes.php.

Now this leads me to think that by declaring the middleware `['middleware' => 'web']` will lead to the code getting called twice, thus clearing the non-persistent flash messages.

A solution based on my assumption would be to simply not use:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
});
```

This is where i found the update information :)
  [Laravel 5.2 Auth not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548061/laravel-5-2-auth-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "web" middleware in the laravel 5.2 from your routes.php file. This way helps me